# Basic Algebra Factoring Problem w/ Parameters?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm having trouble with the following factoring problem, but I'm not even sure if a function like this can be factored to begin with. This is actually a small step in another problem that I'm working on, but this function needs to be factored:

> $f(x) = x - \lambda x^2 -1$ where $0 < \lambda < \frac{1}{4}$

So in general can  functions with parameters like this be factored, and if so, is there a general procedure for getting it done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The discriminant of the quadratic function $f$ is $$\Delta= 1-4\lambda>0$$
then  $f$ has two distinct real roots $x_1=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4\lambda}}{2}$ and $x_2=\frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\lambda}}{2}$ hence we find
$$f(x)=-\lambda(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$$

Comment: this makes sense, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.